# Positioning and maximizing a window that runs in a background task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, winforms, wpf-controls

Ok, following problem:

I have some windows on up to 10 screens that are on one PC. Some of them should be running in background-tasks. Its a WPF-Application, but for the screenpositioning, etc., I use some parts of WinForms. For this I use the following lines:

```
foreach (List<string> myStrings in Screen.AllScreens.Select(myScreen => _xml.GetScreenConfigs(i)))
{
  Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(() =>
  {
    Marketing myMarketing = new Marketing(i, myStrings[0]);
    myMarketing.Show();
    Dispatcher.Run();
  });
  newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
  newWindowThread.Start();
}
```

and inside this Window I use the following to position it:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetActiveWindow();
...
Left = Convert.ToInt32(screenArray[screenNumber].Bounds.Left);
Top = Convert.ToInt32(screenArray[screenNumber].Bounds.Top);
var active = GetActiveWindow();
var singleOrDefault = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
  .SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active);
if (singleOrDefault == null) return;
singleOrDefault.Title = "Monitor" + screenNumber;
singleOrDefault.Name = "Monitor" + screenNumber;
singleOrDefault.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

But when I get to the "var singleOrDefault"-line, I get an error saying that it cannot change the object Application.Current.Windows, because it is owned by another thread.
So my question is the following:

"What can I do, to use this window in a different thread AND to position and maximize it?"

Comment: Are you sure, that you need several UI threads? Why just don't use single UI thread to display results of background operations?

Comment: Yes, because there is a WebBrowser Control that runs multiple times and when I use it with flash (and I have to use flash, there is no way around it), after 3 Controls the app goes down on its knees when all are running on the same thread.

Comment: As I tested, the collection(Application.Current.Windows) only records the windows on the main thread, you can't get your non-main thread windows from it. Are you trying to find the active one from a lot of windows and maximize it?

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)
You wrote:
and inside this Window I use the following to position it:
...
`Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>..`

You cannot operate on the Interop from inside the tasks. Place it in your "master" window. That explains the thread exception.

2)
You may get another thread exception, if you don't use the windows's dispatcher when modifying UIElemetns. That is the idea of the answer from "Captain".
But `Title` `Name` and `Windowstate` seem not to be dependant on the dispatcher, since these should be win32 props.

Comment: Yeah, but how could I maximize the Marketing-Window from inside the App.xaml.cs?

Comment: You don't need to. You let us know: It all happens inside "private void MarketingLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" why not use the sender, for it's common that the loaded element (the "marketing" window) is the sender of the event ? I don't know your overall code, so from my side, try something like: (sender as MarketingWIndow).WindowState = WindowState.Maximized

Comment: I didnt wanted to spam this thread, so please look here for the complete code thats insteresting for this question: http://pastebin.com/s2gPTVSh

Comment: class Marketing isn't a derivate of Window. But it's partial that it seems you share it with a Xaml definition. This looks strange. it should be derived from Window or whatever UserControl

Answer (score 0):

When setting or getting a property of a UI element, you have to invoke the code on the element's Dispatcher's thread.

In short, try this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    var singleOrDefault = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
            .SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active);
    if (singleOrDefault == null) return;
    singleOrDefault.Title = "Monitor" + screenNumber;
    singleOrDefault.Name = "Monitor" + screenNumber;
    singleOrDefault.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: singleOrDefault cannot be used because at the declaration I get the error. I even cannot use the line: var singleOrDefault = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
                .SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active);

Comment: Then wrap the whole block under Dispatcher.Invoke
Starting from 
var singleOrDefault = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>

I edited my answer

Comment: I written it this way, but didnt made any progress. the same error:
Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>{
var singleOrDefault = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
.SingleOrDefault(window => new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle == active);
...});

Comment: You cannot use singleOrDefault.Dispatcher.Invoke(()... before you declare singleOrDefault (what happens a line later).

Comment: Oops. You're right.

Try Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke

Editing my answer again :)

Comment: Ok, that works as far as I dont get more errors, but it doesn't solve my problem. Maybe I have to use the whole procedure inside the App.xaml.cs, instead of the Marketing.xaml.cs.

Comment: Application.Current.Windows is null. So the singleOrDefault variable is also null and cannot be filled.

Comment: Maybe you're running your code too soon, before any window had the chance to load?

Comment: It all happens inside "private void MarketingLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)" and outside of threads it works pretty fine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got (after many tries and errors) a little solution to one of the problems:
Clear everything after the Left=... and Top=... and fill in WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
then it maximizes.
So there is only ONE problem left:
Sometimes (not every start) the app crashes on startup at the line "InitializeComponent();" inside the Marketing.xaml.cs and then again sometimes everything works fine. Sometimes with a null-reference-exception and sometimes it says that there already is a component declared with this name.
Someone an idea here what that could be? Must have to do something with the threading, because its the first time I get these errors.

[edit]
I found it: I have to use a lock(), so now I only have to find out how to use it. Has someone experience with these?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there is the answer I searched nearly two days:

For the Maximizing:
Clear everything after the Left=... and Top=... and fill in WindowState = WindowState.Maximized; then it maximizes.

For the ExceptionErrors:
Put a `static readonly object _locker = new object();` inside the called window and a 
    `lock (_locker)
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }`

inside the windowcall.
Thanks for all the help, I would vote all of your postings up, but I dont have the reputation to do so.